# Google SignIn user authentication opening in Popup window, need to open in same Tab itself using OAuth 2.0

Tags: google-api, google-authentication, googlesigninaccount, google-signin

I am using OAuth 2.0 for google SingIn, it is opening a popup window for user authentication but i want to open in same tab itself, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The popup window opens if you use Google Sign-In JavaScript library. You have to use server side api client libraries to authenticate / authorize without a popup.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ux_mode: redirect` to change Google to Redirect mode which will open in the same tab instead of in a `popup`.
Ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2clientconfig

Then on your redirect landing page, use `auth2.currentUser.get()` to retrieve the signed in Google User object.

---

*(I know this is an old question, but this was one of the first results in a web search; thought it might help others who end up here as well)*